# array removes the last element instead of the removed one react useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoSW2cP-RE

My code is here

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shannon-gz3c2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am trying to delete element when the input field is empty, and it is working in the array (the 2 buttons in the bottom are for logging the array and it's working fine) but in the ordered list something is going wrong, it is deleting the last element and letting the removed one empty not deleting it, what's the problem I don't understand ://

```js
<ol>
  {prosArr.map((e, key) => {
    if (e !== '') {
      console.log(e);
      return (
        <li key={key}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onBlur={(el) => {
              if (el.target.value === '') {
                prosArr[prosArr.indexOf(e)] = '';
                setProsArr(prosArr.filter((e) => e !== ''));
              }
            }}
            defaultValue={e}
          />
        </li>
      );
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  })}
  <li>
    <input
      onBlur={(e) => {
        e.target.value !== '' && setProsArr([...prosArr, e.target.value]);
        e.target.value = '';
      }}
      type="text"
    />
  </li>
</ol>;
```

EDIT: I edited and copied the functionality code here, but there is the full working code on the sandbox link

Comment: you should isolate the code where the functionalty is and attach it to the post as well

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] **in the question itself**

Comment: I'm not really understand how to reproduce the issue.